# Android build tools 1.1.0, New Unit Test JUnit4

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

The new [build tools 1.1.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) states:

> Version 1.1 of Android Studio and the Android gradle plugin brings support for unit testing your code.
> [...]
>
> Unit tests run on a **local JVM** on your development machine.

I assumed that the last statement meant that unit tests are run without needing a device or emulator. Is this correct?

Whenever I try to run the unit tests I still need to choose an emulator or device to run.

Comment: I thought the same thing. I still have to use Robolectric. You can run regular Junit4 tests on your regular Java code. That much, I know.

Comment: How exactly do you 'run the unit tests'?

Comment: In the Run Configurations, I create a new Android Test  for the module. Then click run.

Comment: @JaredBurrows so is the document just misleading, and running on the local JVM is not possible? If so, what's the benefit of enabling this? To allow JUnit 4 in AS instead of JUnit 3?

Comment: @bcorso I believe you are exactly correct. I have tried both the new way, the old way and of course Robolectric. I think it just turns on Junit4. I hope they have better testing support in the future. They have no new tutorials either.

Comment: Running on the JVM is possible, I have a project working like this. Did you enable the experimental feature on Android Studio and select the unit test target on the build variants? Also, try running `./gradlew testDebug` from the command line, it should run the unit tests on a JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was running the wrong type of configuration.

It seems obvious now, but you need to setup a Junit configuration not an AndroidTest configuration (`Run >> Edit Configurations...` click `+` and add a new `Junit` configuration).

To clarify:

- **JUnit:**

  - **Run Configuration:** JUnit
  - **Test Artifact:** Unit Tests
  - **Directory:** src/test/java
- **AndroidTests:**

  - **Run Configuration:** AndroidTest
  - **Test Artifact:** Android Instrumentation Test
  - **Directory:** src/androidTest/java

---

**NOTE:** As far as I know, this new JUnit configuration will only allow you to test the parts of your app that **do not** use the Android API. The benefit being: you can test code in JUnit4 and you can run those test on your local JVM (instead of emulator or device).